# Data Retrival from the GenBank?

Tags: bioinformatics

When I go to NCBI & Select nucleotide option there and in search box write For Example CNGA3 gene the page shows that there are 553 items.I know the method of downloading or retrieving the One item's or record's FASTA format but "if I have to download the FASTA Format of all the 553 items simultaneously without opening each link then what options should I use..?" If you know it then please help me.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy and possible. I will use steps which you already used and add additional steps to answer your question.

1. Go to [Pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed)
2. Select nucleaotide from list
3. Enter gene of interest
4. In format option choose 'FASTA'

[image]

5. Click on send and then complete record
   [image]
6. Click create file and you are ready to go !

Answer (score 1):

I think that using NCBI Gene would be a better option here:

1. Go to NCBI Gene http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/
2. Enter your gene of interest, in this case CNGA3 (and optionally the species)
3. Click the species of interest (I'm assuming you are looking for human, the first search result)
4. On the information page scroll down and click on FASTA which will provide the sequence for the gene of interest.